# Django: my view enters Try part and also Except part?

Tags: python, django

I've a View that, according to my prints, enters the `Try` and the `Except` parts.

As far as I understand, it only should enter the `Try` part or the `Except` part not both.

```
Cart object exist
Lenght in Cart_Items
1
Enters Except PART
55
```

**Why could this be happening?**

```
def cart_detail(request, total = 0, counter = 0, cart_items = None):
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id = request.COOKIES.get("cart_id"))
        if not cart:
            print("No Cart object")
        else:
            print("Cart object exist")
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart = cart)
        print("Lenght in Cart_Items")
        print(len(cart_items))
        for cart_item in cart_items:
            total += (cart_item.product.price)

        sample_items = SampleItem.objects.filter(cart=cart)

        for sample_item in sample_items:
            total += (sample_item.sample.price)


        culqi_my_public_key = settings.CULQI_PUBLISHABLE_KEY #Es necesario mandar la llave pública para generar un token
        culqi_total = int(total * 100) #El total para cualqui debe multiplicarse por 100

        categories = Category.objects.exclude(name='Muestras')

        return render(request, 'cart.html', dict(cart_items = cart_items, sample_items = sample_items, total = total, counter = counter,
                                      culqi_total = culqi_total, culqi_my_public_key = culqi_my_public_key,
                                                 categories = categories))
    except:
        print('Enters Except PART')
        print(request.COOKIES.get("cart_id"))
        categories = Category.objects.exclude(name='Muestras')
        return render(request, 'cart.html', {'categories':categories})
```

Comment: Because something after the bit where you print the length causes an exception. You shouldn't blindly catch all exceptions anyway, and you shouldn't have so much code inside a try.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is wrong. The code *always* enters the `try:` part, *until* an exception is raised. If and when that happens, the `except:` part is run.

So you get the first part of your `try:`, and then the `except:`. Code at the end of the `try:` isn't reached.

Your `try:` part is very long, and you have a so-called "bare-except": you don't say which exceptions you want to catch. Both aren't a good idea, it's better to have short try-parts (so you know exactly which line might throw an exception) and then to catch exactly that exception you expect and nothing else. Otherwise unexpected exceptions will happen without you noticing, because they're silenced by the `except:` block.

Comment: Interesting. Would you mind refactoring my code make those best practices? Anyway ty for your detail answer.

Comment: No time for that (you could try at codereview.stackexchange.com). One tip, if the Cart doesn't exist, it'll throw a Cart.DoesNotExist exception -- you'll never reach the current "No Cart object" line.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be breaking after  `print(len(cart_items))` statement in the try block and then its entering the except block.